# Blocking operation dn't work in Jni Layer function call

Tags: java-native-interface

i have write down a C++ to java call using jni layer.
in java i have to load some big size xml using dom4j at the start.
when it goes for loading, process return back to C++ code, without loading the xml;
Do Jni don't work with blocking operation, 
any input will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I find the root cause, it's not blocking operation, it something else.
:)

Comment: i got an exception during the xml processing, so it comes out, later i implemented exception handling in jni , i find the exception and resolve it, and it works fine... :)

Comment: Yes, you have to be very careful to catch all JNI calls.